# How do I get past the second gate?

Tags: brothers-tale-of-two-sons

In chapter 2, after I free the female orc and trap the male orc, I follow the female orc until we see two gates, the orc holding one of them open. When I go into that first gate, the orc disappears and I can't continue beyond the second gate. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you come to the first gate that the female orc is holding open, this ought to trigger a cut-scene. During the cut-scene, all the characters move through the first and second gate and into the large room.

If something else is happening here, such as a NPC disappearing and your characters not being able to continue, this is probably buggy behavior. (I have tried twice, and have not been able to reproduce this in my version of the game.)

It was difficult to determine specifically what version of the game I have. There are no version numbers anywhere that I could find. I am using the PC version released sometime during 2013.